# ¿Cómo evitar que se repitan datos al usar una concatenación de PHP desde una consulta MYSQL?

Tags: php

Tengo este diseño de estilos CSS, como se puede ver hay dos contenedores diferentes `col-1` y `col-grid`

```
 <div class="col-1">
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fNiFRdd.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-grid">
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fNiFRss.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fNiFRfN.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fNiFRkN.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Para obtener el mismo diseño he usado la concatenación de PHP -> `.=` pero los datos se repiten y no se obtiene el mismo diseño de la estructura `HTML` donde en el primer contenedor va solo una imagen y en el segundo contenedor puede ir más de una imagen, dado al error qué cambios se deben agregar al código para obtener el mismo diseño de la estructura `HTML`

```
    $DivCol = '<div class="col-1">';
    $DivColGrid = '<div class="col-grid">';
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $DivCol .= '<div class="article-two">
                        <img src="'.$cover_page.'">
                    </div>';
        $DivColGrid .= '<div class="article-two">
                        <img src="'.$cover_page.'">
                    </div>';
    }
    $DivColGrid .= '</div>';
    $DivCol .= '</div>';
```

Este es el error que obtengo como resultado, la impresión de datos fue con un `limit de 3` en la consulta `MYSQL`

```
<div class="col-1">
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QCcU9VB.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Sy5jQrQ.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="article-two">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/t6MofoQ.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-grid">
      <div class="article-two">
        <div class="article-two">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QCcU9VB.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="article-two">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Sy5jQrQ.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="article-two">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/t6MofoQ.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola, `$stmt->fetch()` te devuelve 3 datos no? Entonces según el código se va agregar 3 veces a cada div porque estas usando el while, si quieres separar para que te duelve 1 y 3, tendrias que agregar una condicional en tu while

Comment: Claro que se te repetiran, lo que estas diciendo es que mientras halla datos en lo que traes en tu consulta llenas los dos div, la pregunta seria que imagen quieres poner solo en el primer div

Comment: Hola @JuanRivera que condición debo agregar?

Comment: HoLA @NikolaTesla Puede ser cualquier imagen siempre cuando no sea repetido, es decir si obtengo 5 resultados de los últimos registros uno de ellos de todos sus datos debe ir ese div y los otros en los otros div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que puedes probar lo siguente:

```php
$DivCol = '<div class="col-1">';
$DivColGrid = '<div class="col-grid">';
$first = true;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($first) {
        $DivCol .= '<div class="article-two">
                        <img src="' . $cover_page . '">
                    </div>';
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $DivColGrid .= '<div class="article-two">
                        <img src="' . $cover_page . '">
                    </div>';
    }
}
$DivColGrid .= '</div>';
$DivCol .= '</div>';
```

en este caso he agregado la variable `$first` con valor `true`: La primera vez agregará el primer registro al primer `$DivCol` y el resto de las veces a `$DivColGrid`.

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Gracias funciona correctamente.